# How to change body of function TODO() generated on Kotlin?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, comments, todo

I need leave something to do later on my code and `TODO()` auto generated produces a very long comment like follow

```
TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
```

The above line tell me to go to `File -> Setting -> File Template` to change it, but this option not exists to `TODO()` functions. How to solve it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to the Preferences window in Android Studio, select `Editor -> File and Code Templates`, open the `Code` tab, there you will find an option for `New Kotlin Function Body` which you can customize.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Android studio hint wasn't very helpful.