# SensorManager.registerListener causes app to crash

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

The app has no problems until I add the very last line, and when it is commented out, the  app works again:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var  manager: SensorManager
    private lateinit var  accelerometer: Sensor
    private var sensorEventListener = object :SensorEventListener {
        override fun onAccuracyChanged(sensor: Sensor?, accuracy: Int) {
            //TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }

        override fun onSensorChanged(event: SensorEvent) {
            //TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }
    }

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    manager = getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE) as SensorManager;
    accelerometer = manager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    if (accelerometer != null) {
        //THIS LINE CAUSES THE APP TO CRASH
        manager.registerListener(sensorEventListener,accelerometer,SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME)

    } 
}
}
```

Here is the stacktrace:

```
2020-12-17 05:05:32.521 6826-6826/? E/SensorManager: Exception                                                 
dispatching input event.
2020-12-17 05:05:32.522 6826-6826/? A/m.example.labb: java_vm_ext.cc:577] JNI 
DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI CallObjectMethodV called with pending 
exception kotlin.NotImplementedError: An operation is not implemented: Not 
yet implemented
2020-12-17 05:05:32.522 6826-6826/? A/m.example.labb: java_vm_ext.cc:577]   
at void com.example.labb3.MainActivity$sensorEventListener$1.onAccuracyChanged(android.hardware.Sensor, int) (MainActivity.kt:20)
2020-12-17 05:05:32.522 6826-6826/? A/m.example.labb: java_vm_ext.cc:577]   at void android.hardware.SystemSensorManager$SensorEventQueue.dispatchSensorEvent(int, 

float[], int, long) (SystemSensorManager.java:1019)
2020-12-17 05:05:32.522 6826-6826/? A/m.example.labb: java_vm_ext.cc:577]   
at 
void android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(long, int) (MessageQueue.java:-2)
2020-12-17 05:05:32.522 6826-6826/? A/m.example.labb: java_vm_ext.cc:577]   
at 
android.os.Message android.os.MessageQueue.next() (MessageQueue.java:336)
2020-12-17 05:05:32.522 6826-6826/? A/m.example.labb: java_vm_ext.cc:577]   
at 
void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:197)
2020-12-17 05:05:32.522 6826-6826/? A/m.example.labb: java_vm_ext.cc:577]   
at 
void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) 
(ActivityThread.java:8167)
2020-12-17 05:05:32.522 6826-6826/? A/m.example.labb: java_vm_ext.cc:577]   
at 
java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, 
java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
2020-12-17 05:05:32.522 6826-6826/? A/m.example.labb: java_vm_ext.cc:577]   
at 
void com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() 
(RuntimeInit.java:496)
2020-12-17 05:05:32.522 6826-6826/? A/m.example.labb: java_vm_ext.cc:577]   
at 
void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) 
(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
2020-12-17 05:05:32.522 6826-6826/? A/m.example.labb: java_vm_ext.cc:577] 
2020-12-17 05:05:32.522 6826-6826/? A/m.example.labb: java_vm_ext.cc:577]     
in call to CallObjectMethodV
2020-12-17 05:05:32.522 6826-6826/? A/m.example.labb: java_vm_ext.cc:577]     
from void android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(long, int)
2020-12-17 05:05:32.666 6826-6826/? A/m.example.labb: runtime.cc:642] Runtime 
aborting...
```

I have removed parts of the code that are irrelevant, the code that is copied here, however, is tested and is shown to have the very same faulty behavior.
I wonder what I am doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace from the log?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It has been added in original post now.

Comment: Thanks to your comment, I now know that unlike in Java, Kotlin does not add a commented out "Unimplemented function", but adds code that causes this exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that unlike in Java, Kotlin does not add a commented out "Unimplemented function" or throws a function unimplemented exception, but adds code that causes this problem, namely:
TODO("Not yet implemented")

Comment: This behavior can be customized: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55834530/how-to-change-body-of-function-todo-generated-on-kotlin

Comment: If the issue is fixed pls mark it accepted .

Comment: I will when the website allows me (Which is after 48 hours :)  )